# NSDateFormatter only works on simulator?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

i simple try to reformat a date:

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 NSDate *date = [[NSData alloc] init];
 //Mon, 05 Apr 2010 14:27:48 -0700
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
 date = [formatter dateFromString:self.currentItemValue];        

 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
 self.currentItem.pubDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
 [formatter release];
```

It works on the simulator, but on the device i only get (null).

Thanks for your help!

Some more tests:

```
NSString *string = @"Fri, 12 Dec 2008 18:45:15 -0800";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
//here i got (null) on the device but it works on simulator...
NSLog(@"date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: What region is the device set to?

Comment: I try something else.. i edited my question...

Comment: On the device, under Settings, General, International, what is Region Format set to?  If it's not an English region, you'll need to use setLocale method in date formatter and set it to en_US so it can parse the English day and month names in your input strings.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559182/how-do-you-interpret-dates-with-nsdateformatter/1559284#1559284 for example.

Comment: My timezone is "Berlin", region Format is "German"

Answer (score 6):

DyingCactus was right!

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease]];
```

solves my issue.... Thanks!!!!

Comment: [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];